# USB ports not functioning on Lenovo Ideapad Y570

Tags: laptop, usb

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Y570 laptop, and currently there is a problem with the USB ports. The only thing the computer recognized from the USB peripherals was some old keyboard I found. I presume the problem comes from the power supply of the USB interface, since the problem occurs on all 3 of them, and the keyboard has the least power requirements (compared to flash drives, smartphones, etc..). I don't have a laptop warranty anymore, what would be the solution in my case?

Comment: If you presume something, why don't you conduct a simple experiment to confirm your presumption/assumption? Take a USB cable, cut it in half, expose black and red wires (ground and VBUS), and load them with 10-Ohm resistor. The voltage between the wires should stay around 5V before and after loading. If not, you will need to open the laptop, and examine polyfuses that connect USB port VBUS to 5V power. If you can't do this, get a new laptop, Y570 is five years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect other devices than keyboard, does the system at least reports there's unrecognizable device connected?

If yes, you're correct - the power supply to those ports is failing.

Solutions to this one are simple:

1. replace the motherboard
2. use powered USB hub with external supply of at least 5A.

If answer to above question is no, try this:
https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/documents/ht070256